# Connection to Mac is lost after certain time of inactivity

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 (15.6.5) on Windows 10 and I'm developing with Xamarin. I pair my computer with a MacBook Air in order to develop for iPhone.

After a time of "inactivity" the connection with the Mac is not "valid" any more.

The explanation for the terms that I used in quotes is the following:

Inactivity - Time between 2 consecutives run/build the application. So I'm running the application now and I'm running again the application after 30 minutes. Usually the time of inactivity is about 20 to 30 minutes (It's not one day)

Valid - The connection with the Mac is not actually lost. The icon at the toolbar that shows the connection to the Mac is still green and when I open the dialog I can see that Visual Studio is still paired with the Mac. But when I'm trying to build the app, I'm getting the message "An active connection to the Mac is required in order to run the application. Please ensure the connection is established and try again." as if Visual Studio is not connected to the Mac.

I have to close the simulator and Visual Studio in order to be able to build again the application.

The Mac is connected to the local network with WiFi.

So the questions are why this is happening and how can I correct it?

Thanks

Comment: Although the ip on the Mac is not static, it doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

I had this before and it was becuase the mac would go into sleep mode. Changing the timout settings in system preferences fixed it for me

Comment: I was talking about normal situations and when the Mac is not in sleep mode. Indeed, after going to sleep mode then the connection is lost.